# 180 panoramic based on multiple cameras

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, compute-module, compute-module-3

Need some help please  :)

I would need some help to find the best option for a product upgrade. Right now, it consists of a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with the Camera Module v2 and an external mobile application to receive the videos through the cloud. The single board is connected to a PoE switch though Ethernet so it doesn't require double wiring. The upgrade that I need is to create a **non-distorting 180 panoramic video recording camera** in realtime.

**The basic requisites are:**

- 180 degrees non-distorting panoramic FOV
- Store only 1 video in total
- A minimum of 30 FPS since it records fast movements
- Good resolution if possible
- Ethernet port (better if supports PoE)
- USB or 3mm for Audio Input
- Handling at least 8 hours of recording a day (sometimes with high temperature)

**The solution that I was thinking was:**

- Using Raspberry Pi Compute Module
- Using 2 cameras to get the 180 degrees by placing one camera next to the other *(i.e. https://www.spinelelectronics.com/5mp_usb_cameras/UC50MPC this camera is great because of being 5MP non-distorting 110 angle FOV, but the problem is that is a USB camera and that would probably consume more CPU than a MIPI CSI camera.)*
- Real-time panoramic stitching to get a single video

Based on this information, what combination of single-board computer, cameras and panoramic generation option would be the best?

I would really appreciate your answers.  :)